# how to search an array for letters

Tags: c++

was looking over this program and im trying to figure out how to search for letters in an array instead of numbers, it works for numbers but how can i make it work for letters. please help............... here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int DECLARED_SIZE = 4;

void fillArray(int a[], int size, string& letter);
int search(const int a[], string letter, string target);

int main( )
{
    int arr[DECLARED_SIZE]; string listletter; string target;
    fillArray(arr, DECLARED_SIZE, listletter);
    char ans;
    int result;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a letter to search for: ";
        cin >> target;
        result = search(arr, listletter, target);
        if (result == -1)
            cout << target << " is not on the list.\n";
        else
            cout << target << " is stored in array position "
            << result << endl
            << "(Remember: The first position is 0.)\n";
        cout << "Search again?(y/n followed by Return): ";
        cin >> ans;
    } while ((ans != 'n') && (ans != 'N'));
    cout << "End of program.\n";
    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int a[], int size, string& letter)
{
    cout << "Enter up to " << size << " letter.\n"
        << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";
    int next, index = 0;
    cin >> next;
    while ((next >= 0) && (index < size))
    {
        a[index] = next;
        index++;
        cin >> next;
    }
}

int search(const int a[], string numberUsed, string target)
{
    int index  = 0; 
    string run = "run";
    bool found = false;

    while ((!found)) // && (index < numberUsed))
        if (target == run)
            found = true;
        else
            index++;

    if (found)
        return index;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is it you need help with, what error message do you get?

Comment: Yikes. Eye cancer alert! Try using whitespace, indentation, formatting, and a basic sense of aesthetics!

Comment: Homework, is it? As Anders K. says, what have you tried and what is not working? People on SO answer questions, not write code for you.

Comment: You might want to use `char`s for storing individual letters, as opposed to a whole `string` or `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're loading an int in fillArray.  You need to use char if you want character input.

```
void fillArray(int a[], int size, string& letter)
{
 cout << "Enter up to " << size << " letter.\n"
 << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";
 char next;
 int index = 0;
 cin >> next;
 while ((next >= 0) && (index < size))
 {
   a[index] = next;
   index++;
 cin >> next;
 }
}
```

Comment: You have changed the local variable to `char` but have not changed the array type passed to the function. There is also an unused argument, `string& letter` but that was present in the original code.

Comment: I was trying to minimize the changes required to the original code, but you have a good point.  Even though char can be stored as an int, a char array should be used to make it clear what you're working with.